# Laravel 5.5 tinymce add 2 instead of more than one space

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.5

I use tinymce as my website Editor, when i want to add more than one space and save my text i see that editor replace my spaces by 2, i try many ways just like add encoding in config.js file but i cannot handle that, please help me to reomve the 2 numbers from my text :

the sample text is :

```
this is test  test  test
```

the editor save as :

```
this is test2 2 test2 2test
```

My Html Code :

```
<form action="{{route('admin.setting.guarantee.text.store')}}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="gtext_form">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea data-tinymce id="guaranteeText" name="guaranteeText" class="form-control">@if(\App\GuaranteeText::count() > 0) {{\App\GuaranteeText::first()->Text}} @endif</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="ثبت متن گارانتی" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On client side, you could use a function to replace spaces `" "` by `&nbsp` on while typing.

With jQuery:

```
$("#guaranteeText").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp"));
});
```

If your intention was really to replace a single space by two spaces :

```
$("#guaranteeText").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp&nbsp"));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but keyup dose not work for me :( , my problem is that the editor store 2 , and i have problem in my database too !